# What is the accepted way for admin-only tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not using devise for learning purposes. I want admins to be able to access an admin-only page.

I've created an `admin` attribute with boolean type and default value of false. So I can check if someone is an admin by something like `current_user.admin?`.

I am doing admin check something like

```
before_action :admin_check, only: :show

def admin_check
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
end
```

safe in terms of security?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this looks safe to me if you remove the `only: :show` part. You want to protect your other actions as well, I guess...

Also, I assume that an unprivileged user has no way of reaching that controller through normal navigation, so I'd probably also invalidate his session, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

That solution is "safe" for basic purposes as long as you're careful about including that check where it is needed.

For more advanced role-based abilities, look into the [CanCanCommunity gem](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan).

With CanCan the action would look something like this:

```
def show
  authorize! :manage, @setting
  ...
end
```